# oracle distinct doing sort

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm getting poor performance from DISTINCT.  The explain plan indicates that it is doing SORT (GROUP BY) which doesn't sound right.  I would expect some kind of HASH aggregation to produce much better result.  Is there a hint to tell oracle to use HASH for DISTINCT rather than sort?
I've used /*+ USE_HASH_AGGREGATION */ in similar situations, but it is not working for DISTINCT.

So this is my original query:

```
SELECT
count(distinct userid) n, col
FROM users
GROUP BY col;
```

users has 30M rows, each userid is there 12 times.  This query takes 70 seconds.

Now we rewrite it as

```
SELECT
count(userid) n, col
FROM
(SELECT distinct userid, col FROM users)
GROUP BY col
```

And it takes 40 seconds.
Now add the hint to do hash instead of sort:

```
SELECT
count(userid) n, col
FROM
(SELECT /*+ USE_HASH_AGGREGATION */ distinct userid, col FROM users)
GROUP BY col
```

and it takes 10 seconds.

If somebody can explain to me why this is happening or how I can beat the first simple query into working as good as the 3rd one, that would be fantastic.
The reason I care about query simplicity is because these queries are actually generated.

Plans:
1) Slow:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation      | Name          | Starts | E-Rows | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers | Reads  |  OMem |  1Mem | Used-Mem | Used-Tmp|
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |               |      1 |        |      5 |00:01:12.01 |     283K|    292K|       |       |      |     |
|   1 |  SORT GROUP BY     |               |      1 |      5 |      5 |00:01:12.01 |     283K|    292K|   194M|   448K|  172M (0)|   73728 |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| USERS |      1 |     29M|     29M|00:00:08.17 |     283K|    283K|       |       |      |     |
```

2) Fast

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation        | Name          | Starts | E-Rows | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers | Reads  |  OMem |  1Mem | Used-Mem |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT     |               |      1 |        |      5 |00:00:13.09 |     283K|    283K|   |   |      |
|   1 |  SORT GROUP BY       |               |      1 |      5 |      5 |00:00:13.09 |     283K|    283K|  3072 |  3072 | 2048  (0)|
|   2 |   VIEW               |               |      1 |   8647K|   2445K|00:00:13.16 |     283K|    283K|   |   |      |
|   3 |    HASH UNIQUE       |               |      1 |   8647K|   2445K|00:00:12.57 |     283K|    283K|   113M|    10M|  216M (0)|
|   4 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL| USERS         |      1 |     29M|     29M|00:00:07.68 |     283K|    283K|   |   |      |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: +1 : Good spot, good work, and good luck.  I'm also intrigued by this one.

Comment: Could you show the explain/execution plans for each of the queries? Also, one should note that the `USE_HASH_AGGREGATION` hint is officially undocumented.

Comment: Cross-posted from [dba.se]: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13028

Comment: when you run the sql - check the CPU % usage and memory usage, maybe the machine you're running on is limited.

Comment: @AdamHawkes how dangerous is using an undocumented hint?  I have other things that totally depend on it, Oracle keeps sorting instead of hashing for group bys.  I will try to get exec plans here in a minute.

Comment: @alfasin as far as I know, I'm pretty much the only user on the system and it has 10+ cores.

Comment: Undocumented hints are not usually "dangerous", but their use should be carefully monitored. Oracle can, and has, eliminated some undocumented hints going from one version to the next. Occasionally they may cause unexpected/inaccurate results, but not often.

Comment: @AdamHawkes K, thanks.  I've posted the plans btw.

Comment: @MK. run "top" to check it. maybe there's a problem. also I would run "ps -ef | grep -i sql" to see how many threads are running.

Comment: Closed as cross-site post: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13028/oracle-distinct-doing-sort

Comment: @casperOne close, really?  With 9 upvotes? 70 views here vs 20 there? I'm not stupid, i xposted out of desperation.

Comment: @MK. Yes, really.  If you willingly posted the *same exact content* on another site, it gets closed on the site that is the less specialized of the sites.  This behavior is *highly* frowned upon on Stack Exchange. If you want, we can migrate this over and have it merged with the question on DBA.  Desperation does not justify cross-posting like that.

Comment: @casperOne There are more people reading it here.  That's all.

Comment: @MK. I'm sorry, but none of those factors matter.  If you want it closed and deleted on the DBA site and then reopened here, we *might* be able to do that (but that's *highly* unlikely).  This question belongs on the DBA site, by your own admission.

Comment: @casperOne I'm not sure why the fact that it is more helpful to me to have this question here doesn't matter.  It belongs on DBA by the SE rules.  I do not like these rules.  I think SO got over-fragmented for not good reason and this question is a perfect example of that.

Answer (score 2):

How about trying the following:
If you had an index on col and userid it should resolve completely in the index and not need to touch the table at all.

```
Select count(userid) n, col
from (select col, userid from users group by col, userid)
group by col
;
```

Comment: index helps if the table is very wide, but my numbers are for the narrow table so index doesn't help.